# Solidity Compiling Command(foundry)

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I was learning to run the test.sol.

I command `forge test -m testFundUpdatesFundedDataStructure`
and I faced the error with `unexpected argument '-m' found`

- How can I compile this?
- Did I miss something?

---

My code was fine, and I think there's something wrong with the command.

However I've tried `forge test`, it did compile success.

Can anyone tell me what was going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foundry has updated their CLI flags. So you no longer have `-m` or `--match`.

Instead you're supposed to use `--match-test` or shorthand `--mt` to specify your test function regex. Here's the [official documentation](https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-test#test-options) for more reference.